# computer organization : finding control word length

Tags: computer-architecture

A microprogram control unit is required to generate a total of 35 control signals. Assume that during any microinstruction, at most 2 control signals are active. The minimum number of bits required in the control word to generate the required control signal will be

a.2 b.6 c.7 d.8 ?

Please explain how to calculate this?

Comment: There's clearly some context missing. If you have 35 control signals and you need to select any two, any one, or none of them, then surely that requires $\left\lceil \log_2 \left( {35 \choose 0} + {35 \choose 1} + {35 \choose 2} \right) \right\rceil = 10$ bits.

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 0):

The options are wrong. The answer is 10.

Check  [here](http://web.iiit.ac.in/~ramaraju/GATE.txt)  for proper options (although sadly, the question is wrong :( )